# Overwrite a specific VBO action processed message

Tags: views, 9, actions

I am using VBO to perform bulk operations on my view. I have 2 core VBO actions and 2 custom actions.

- Publish comment
- Unpublish comment
- Publish resource
- Unpublish resource

When the *Apply action* button is clicked with none of the grid row is selected, I get this error message.

> Select one or more comments to perform the update on.

I would like to rewrite this error message as *An attachment has to be selected to perform this action*.

How can I achieve this? I am aware of `hook_views_bulk_operations_finish()`, but it doesn't overwrite a specific action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. Define your own ViewsField plugin that extends the CommentBulkForm (that is where that message comes from)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\your_module\Plugin\views\field;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\BulkForm;

/**
 * Defines a custom comment operations bulk form element.
 *
 * @ViewsField("custom_comment_bulk_form")
 */
class CustomCommentBulkForm extends CommentBulkForm {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function emptySelectedMessage() {
    return $this->t('An attachment has to be selected to perform  this action.');
  }

}
```

2. Expose your plugin to views:

```
function your_module_views_data() {

  $data['comment']['custom_comment_bulk_form'] = [
    'title' => t('Custom comment operations bulk form'),
    'help' => t('Add a form element that lets you run operations on multiple comments, with custom messages.'),
    'field' => [
      'id' => 'custom_comment_bulk_form',
    ],
  ];

  return $data;
}
```

3. Finally, overwrite (or override) your (views.view.) Comments configuration so that your existing 'Comment: Comment operations bulk form' field is forced to use your ViewsField plugin. One way to overwrite would be via drush:

```
drush cset views.view.comment \
  display.default.display_options.fields.comment_bulk_form.field \
  custom_comment_bulk_form
```

That would eventually allow you to set your own custom message:

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Got a question. I have created the ViewsField plugin inside my module at this path - mymodule\src]plugin\views\field\custom_comment_bulk_form.php. But this path is nowhere referenced, neither in hook_views_data() nor in the config file. So how will my custom plugin file be read?

Comment: also I get to see "Error: Class 'Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\BulkForm\CommentBulkForm' not found in include()" error from the plugin. :(

Comment: nm, this worked like a charm!! thanks a lot!

Comment: If i want to update the message of other actions like "delete comment" or "unpublish comment" can i use the above mentioned solution?

Comment: This message is used (and shared) by the various actions available via the CommentBulkForm ViewsField plugin.

Comment: can you add a sample for updating "Delete comment" message? I want to update it mainly from View bulk operations module perspective

Comment: That would need a separate question I believe.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/308652/alter-action-processing-results-message-for-a-specific-action - I have this almost working except i'm struck with a condition. would you mind checking this question? thanks