# Alter "Action processing results" message for a specific action

Tags: views, hooks

I have a view based on view bulk operations. this is a comment based view and performs the below actions:

```
1. Publish comment 2. Unpublish comment
```

When one of these actions are selected to be executed on a set of records, I get to see a success message like below:

```
Action processing results: Unpublish Comment (1).
```

I would like to alter the success message as:

```
The selected comment(s) have been unpublished successfully
```

I am using VBO 4.0.0 which has action processing message update commit in it. No clue about how this can be implemented for a specific actions. any help?

UPDATE:

Below is my trial so far:

```
function mymod_batch_alter(&$batch) {
  foreach ($batch['sets'] as $key => $set) {
      $batch['sets'][$key]['finished'] = 'mymod_views_bulk_operations_execute_finished';
    }
  }

/**
 * Implements hook_views_bulk_operations_execute_finish().
 */
function mymod_views_bulk_operations_execute_finished($success, array $results, array $operations) {
    if ($success) {
      $operations = $results['operations'];
      if($operations == "Approve Comment"){
        $message = \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Success! Approved');
      }
      elseif($operations == "Disapprove Comment"){
        $message = \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Success! Disapproved');
      }
    }
    else {
      $message = \Drupal::messenger()->addWarning('Failure message...');
    }
    return NULL;
  }
```

This code is working well, but just one issue. everytime, even for the "disapprove comment" action, I get to see "Success! Approved" message. Control is going into wrong if-condition. Can someone point the mistake out?

Comment: You are assigning (single =) inside both conditions; you should be comparing (double ==)

Comment: I tried that. still no luck

Comment: Please update your code sample above to reflect the corrections I suggested.

Comment: updated my code

Comment: You are reading the array incorrectly on top of using = to check equality, as I was saying in the question you deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the below code works:

```
function mymod_batch_alter(&$batch) {
  foreach ($batch['sets'] as $key => $set) {
      $batch['sets'][$key]['finished'] = 'mymod_views_bulk_operations_execute_finished';
    }
  }

/**
 * Implements hook_views_bulk_operations_execute_finish().
 */
function mymod_views_bulk_operations_execute_finished($success, array $results, array $operations) {
    if ($success) {
      $operations = $results['operations'];
      if($operations[0] == "Approve Comment"){
        $message = \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Success! Approved');
      }
      elseif($operations[0] == "Disapprove Comment"){
        $message = \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Success! Disapproved');
      }
    }
    else {
      $message = \Drupal::messenger()->addWarning('Failure message...');
    }
    return NULL;
  }
```